# Service registry and external services

Tags: java, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

With my custom applications I can use service registry and ribbon to automatically get fail-over built in my `RestTemplate`. I would like to have the same with external services, let's say elastic-search nodes. I would like to have a `RestTemplate` that gets working nodes from eureka and uses this information to do fail-over. how can I do that? Or is it possible to achieve the same thing in another way?